# Is there a mistake in diagramatic representation of RS perturbation theory described in Szabo and Ostlund textbook?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, erratum

I'm trying to understand rules of the diagrammatic representation of the many body perturbation theory that described in Szabo and Ostlund "Modern Quantum Chemistry" textbook. One of the first rules they introduced is the following:

*"Each pair of adjacent dots contributes the denominator $$\sum E_{hole}^{(0)} - \sum E_{particle}^{(0)}$$ where sums run over the labels of all hole and particle lines crossing an imaginary horizontal line separating the two adjacent dots."*

According to that rule and other rules described in this book, the sum of the following diagrams:

[image]

can be translated as follows:

$$-\sum_{n,m\neq i}\frac{2|V_{ni}|^2|V_{mi}|^2}{(E^0_{i}-E^0_{m})(2E^0_{i}-E^0_{n}-E^0_{m})(E^0_{i}-E^0_{n})}$$

The idea of authors was that if we sum all possible n-dots diagrams we will get the exact expression for n<sup>th</sup>-order correction to energy. However, for the fourth-order perturbation theory there are no terms with such a denominator factor:

$$(2E^0_{i}-E^0_{n}-E^0_{m})$$

Am I right that in the case of 4<sup>th</sup>-order perturbation theory there is no direct mapping between those diagrams and strict algebraic formulations?